# Need to put two NIS servers in yp.conf file

Tags: linux, nis, yp

How do I configure 2 servers in yp.conf

I tried :
*domain domain.com server server1 server2*

but it seems to take the first one

Tried: 
*domain domain.com server server1 
domain domain.com server server2*

But i am not sore its working.

man yp.conf (or ypbind) does not help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use only ONE server per config line:

```
 domain ypdomain server ypserver1
 domain ypdomain server ypserver2
 .
 .
 .
```

Comment: FIrst of all many thanks. 2nd I truly trust you, but where can I find it in the man or other documentation?Thanks

Comment: Its in the `man` page for `yp.conf`.